# "active object is not a selected mesh" error

Tags: mesh, objects

Trying to join different meshes together.

In object mode, if I select a couple of objects and try to join them I get the error `active object is not a selected mesh`.

If I select the meshes, it puts me into `Edit Mode` and the `join` command is not visible.

If I select meshes in `edit mode` then change to object mode I get the error `no data to join`.

It's super confusing.   What am I doing wrong?

What I am actually trying to do is to simplify a model, by joining parts with similar shaders together, for import into three.js . I want less data in the json file and want to make it simpler to animate in three.js, with less objects. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: How are you selecting the multiple objects?  Are you using [C] (circle select), [B] (box select), [A] (toggle select/deselect all), or [Shift]+clicking?

Comment: [Shift]+clicking in the outliner - crazy enough I found selecting multiple objects really complicated, it took me a while to even figure out how to do it. I'm used to the maya interface o.O

Comment: You use right click to select in Blender.  It seems strange at first but after a while you realize it's quite handy, you can change it in the user preferences if you want though.  Try right clicking one object, then shift-clicking the rest.

Comment: This happens when you accidentally selected something like the camera or a lamp

Comment: Thanks. I'm just clicking on meshes. or objects. What's the difference between selecting something in the outliner where the text turns white, and  Shift +RMB clicking where the layer background in the outliner turns gray, but the text does not turn white?   When making multiple selections, should each layer have white text? and should each mesh layer look orange in the main window on the model itself? That's what I would think would be logical, but that's not happening in my case.

Comment: [I'm playing around with this model](https://clara.io/view/64d4efc0-1f7e-4d11-ad2c-77fdabdeefd8#) .  For instance if I try to join the layers `sole-foam` with `air-bubble-left` and `air-bubble-right`, it's not happening, I get the error `no mesh data to join` :(

Comment: that is strange, I could join them instantly with CTRL+J in object mode. I selected the objects in th 3D view SHIFT+ RMB

Comment: Cool I'll try again, what's kbd ?

Comment: ignore that kbd

Comment: Nope, I still can't do it :( strange. What's the visual supposed to look like when you're successful at selecting multiple meshes? are all orange? Are all white text in the outliner? Maybe somethings up with my configuration, on a mac.

Comment: They are all orange in the 3D view. Maybe you should try it this way. Select all in object mode click on A (all the objects are orange) then click on H, to hide all the objects. Go to the outliner and click on the eyes for the objects you want to join. Then in 3D view select all with A (objects outlines are orange if they are selected) and then CTRL + J

Comment: By the way you could set the interaction to Maya in the splashscreen when you start up blender. Or you could set it in the user preferences CTRL+ALT+U --> input --> presets -->maya

Comment: Finally. Thank you good suggestion to turn off the other layers o.O ! Wow, Blender is really unintuitive imho.  I don't seem to be able to multiple select via the outliner, but was successful in the 3d window.

Comment: Are you sure that none of these meshes have modifiers on them? If so, try to apply them all.

Answer (score 11):

In order for selected mesh to combine make sure one of these objects is text highlighted in the outliner, it's a means for Blender to decide which part inherits the other parts. If none of the parts are text highlighted you will get that error message and they won't combine.

Answer (score 4):

So I got around it by right click selecting two objects in objects mode. One yellow outlined and one orange. The With them highlighted press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> now that the two objects are one, select them (it) in object mode and select the remaining objects by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> and selecting them with a left click again. Your original objects should be highlighted in yellow and the ones you wish to join will be in orange. Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> again and you are done. There might be an easier way but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Click on first object. then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the other object you want to join., then right click and hit *Join*.

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, in the collection i had disable selection, but enable selection on the two object that i wanted to join so i got the error message posted above ver. 2.93

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

You can only do two objects at a time. Select the two objects you want to combine then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Not true, you can select multiple objects and join them with Ctrl J

Comment: Agree, not true, interestingly doing two objects at a time did fix my issue